# WorkFront (AtTask) assign Task

Tags: attask, workfront-api

I am having my challenges using WorkFronts API.  My current problem is that I cannot figure out how to use their assign action method.  WorkFront's documentation says that the assign method accepts two arguments; objID and objCode.  Below is what I have currently.  I have tried other URL's, but I keep getting the same error message.  The error that is being returned is NullPointerException.  If anybody could help that would be great.  Also if you happen to have working examples that you could pass my way or some kind of documentation.  I have these two URL's; https://developers.workfront.com/api-docs/ and https://developers.workfront.com/api-docs/api-explorer/.  The API Explorer API shows you the assign action method on the Task object.

```
    using (var apiManagementSystem = new HttpClient())
    {
        apiManagementSystem.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://xxxxxxx.preview.workfront.com/attask/api/");
        apiManagementSystem.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

        var jsonMediaType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
        apiManagementSystem.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(jsonMediaType);
        apiManagementSystem.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SessionID", _sessionID);

        HttpContent httpContent = null;
        responseMessage = apiManagementSystem.PutAsync("v6.0/TASK/TASKID/assign?objID=TASKID&objCode=TASK&apiKey=ApiKey", httpContent).Result;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke the assign method under the object that you wish assign an object to (the work) to and then provide as arguments the ID and type of the object that you are assigning (the worker).

For example: `<baseurl>/task/<taskID>/assign?objID=<userID>&objCode=USER`

The above snippet would assign the user specified by userID to the task specified by taskID. Ensure that you pass the call as a PUT method.

Valid assignee object types are: users, roles, or teams.

Comment: this works.  Thanks.  You wouldn't happen to know how to assign a list of people would you?  I tried calling the assign action method on multiple people, however that unassign's the current person assigned and assigns the new person.

Comment: This was quite simple.  All you had to do was get the ID of the user who was to be assigned and also get the project id for the project where the assignee was to be assigned and then post that data.

Comment: Did you ever find the way to assign multiple users to a task?